# Can’t access Kudu (scm) Error 403 - This web app is stopped

Tags: azure, kudu

I can’t access Kudu (scm) on any of my web apps: “error 403 this web app is stopped”. The app are running fine also all other serviçes.

I have changed my microsoft account autentication mode to Two-step verification.

Any ideias?

Comment: Is this the same as https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/issues/2997.  If so, let use that for communication.

Comment: @SuwatCh Thanks for help me, the problem occurs only with the brave browser.